# How do I modify frontend codes for upload feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, go

I want to get updating info including upload file feature, for backend codes, it's above:

```
http.HandleFunc("/uploadHeadurlHandler", uploadHeadurlHandler)

file, image, err := r.FormFile("picture")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(" -- Failed to FormFile, err:", err)
    message(w, code.CodeMsg[code.CodeFormFileFailed])
    return
}
```

frontend side codes are below as:

```
<form action="/userinfo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>username</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="username" value="{{.Username}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>password</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nickname</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nickname" value="{{.Nickname}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="file" name="upload" value="{{.Headurl}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="update">
```

```
<script>
    $("#file").on("change", function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", $("#file")[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/uploadHeadurlHandler",
            type: "POST",
            data: {picture:formData},
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("upload success")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

***now backend error is:***  `Failed to FormFile, err: request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data`

I suspended there are some issues on frontend side, I'm a fresh on frontend, anyone can tell me how do I change the above frontend side.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is expecting a `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data`, but that is not what your frontend is sending.

With jQuery, you need to [set the `data` field to the actual `FormData` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031) you want to send.
To set the correct name you're expecting on your server, you should also change the name to `picture` on your front-end.

When you apply these changes it looks like this:

```
<script>
    $("#file").on("change", function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("picture", $("#file")[0].files[0]); // <- changed the form file name 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/uploadHeadurlHandler",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData, // <- send the actual FormData object
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("upload success")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

That way, uploads should work. Then you need to rename the `name` of the input field in your HTML form to make sure they also work without JavaScript (if the `action` of the form is set correctly etc.):

```
<tr>
    <td>file</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="file" name="picture" value="{{.Headurl}}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: your answer solved my problem, thank you, have accepted